# Бесконечный поток Java

Tags: java, многопоточность

````
       File folderIn = new File("C:\\Users\\HP\\OneDrive\\Skrivebord\\to"); // Enter your link

       Redactor radactor1 = new Redactor(folderIn);

       Thread thread2 = new Thread(radactor1);

       for(;;){
           thread2.start();
           thread2.join();
           thread2.sleep(1000);
       }

   } ```





Здравствуйте, проблема что я получаю содержание из папки и вывожу на консоль, мне надо чтобы оно проверяло состояние папки каждую секунду. Я сделал бесконечный цикл, но выводит ошибку




```Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalThreadStateException
   at java.base/java.lang.Thread.start(Thread.java:794)
   at Leks6.Main.main(Main.java:18)```
````

Comment: Не ответ на вопрос, но мелочь: `thread2.sleep(1000)` -> `Thread.sleep(1000)`. [sleep](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#sleep-long-) - статический метод, который приостанавливает **текущую** нить. Ваш синтаксис формально верный, но вводит в заблуждение, как будто имеет отношение к объекту `thread2`.

Comment: thread2 запускает ведь метод run, который в свою очередь запускает поток, thread2.sleep(1000) останавливает только данный поток,  если у нас будет открыты 5 потоков они все ведь будут ожидать, если Thread.sleep(1000)

Comment: Вы ошибаетесь. `Thread.sleep` останавливает только одну нить, ту из которой вызван. `thread2.sleep` останавливает только одну нить, ту из которой вызван. На поведение `thread2` вызов не влияет.

Comment: Благодарю, только месяц изучаю ООП, и сейчас на многопоточности.

Answer (score 1):

```
for(;;){
        Thread thread2 = new Thread(radactor1);
        thread2.start();
        thread2.join();
        thread2.sleep(1000);
    }
```

Comment: Ваш ответ можно улучшить с помощью дополнительной информации. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] для добавления подробностей, например, цитат или документации, чтобы другие могли подтвердить правильность вашего ответа. Вы можете найти дополнительную информацию о том, как писать хорошие ответы [в Справке](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Красивее будет выглядеть код, если заменить for(;;) на while(true). Как по мне меньше точек с запятой выглядит лучше

Comment: Действительно стало красивее )